# android doesn't show menu when using fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-menu

I was using `activity`, then i want to change my code to use `viewpager` with `fragment`

what i was using activity, i was able to show the `menu`. however, when i changed my code to fragment, i am not able to show the menu.

#### code

This code in the fragment

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.all_restaurants, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call [`setHasOptionsMenu(true)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setHasOptionsMenu%28boolean%29) for the Fragment.

Eg using the Fragment's `onCreate()` method

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
```

You also do not need the call to `super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);`, the superclass method is empty.

Comment: you are amazing, what is that please? i will accept the answer after 13minutes

Comment: just one think please, the menu items are without images, although they have images and these images were shown when i was using activity

Comment: @user3110137 I'm not entirely sure why. Activities that use `Theme.Holo` or `Theme.AppCompat` variants won't show icons unless the menu items are in the visible part of the `ActionBar, but I don't know if that applies to you.

Comment: In another activity, I am using action bar, and a `theme.appcompat` and when i press menu, i got menu items with images. Also, in your solution, the menu is not what i used to see, i will post the image of the menu

Comment: @user3110137 Also post the image with your other `Activity` that *does* show icons.

Comment: I just posted the image of activity that has menu which is different from the menu above

Comment: @user3110137 Look at the themes, they are *clearly* different. The one **with** the icons is *not* using `Theme.AppCompat` variant and it is most certainly not extending `ActionBarActivity`. If you want the icons to show, add them to your [`ActionBar`](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html) (read from `If your app is using the Support Library...`)

Comment: yes it is not extended `actionnbaractivity`. so please isn't any way to add these images?

Comment: what do you mean by `ead from If your app is using the Support Library...)` please? also, do you mean that i have to add them to the action bar by using in the menu xml `showasaction` ?

Comment: I mean, you start reading from the sentence that starts with `If your app is using the Support Library...`. And yes, using `Theme.AppCompat` or `Theme.Holo`, icons **only** show if they are in the ActionBar (using `setShowAsAcion`).